# Product of a nondecreasing unbounded sequence and convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can not prove the following statement. Could you please help me? Thanks

Prove that for each $a_k>0$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k< \infty $ there exists a nondecreasing unbounded sequence $(b_k)^\infty_{k=1}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k a_k< \infty $

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with $b_k = 1$ for all $k$?

Comment: I edit the question and add bk is unbounded. So bk is an nondecreasing unbounded sequence that goes from 1 to infinity

Comment: Choose an increasing sequence $(n_m)$ such that $$\sum_{k = n_m}^{\infty} a_k < \frac{1}{m^3}.$$ Choose $b_k$ constant on $n_m \leqslant k < n_{m+1}$.

Comment: If $S_n=\sum_{k\geq n} a_k$, you can put $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{S_n}}$, and use the inequality
$$b_na_n=\frac{S_n-S_{n+1}}{\sqrt{S_n}}\leq \int_{S_{n+1}}^{S_n}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$